# how to delete header in datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

how to delete header in datagridview in C# including both rows and columns data? I have tried many but only deletes row and column data,but not the header.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it is possible to delete row and column headers (likely not), but you can at least hide them:

```
grid.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
grid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

Comment: thanks it worked.. but did not delete the header..

Comment: @Pret, as i said it **hides** headers. for display purpose it should be the same as if headers are "deleted". but can you give more details, please? why it is not enough?

Comment: how to view the data in datagridview from sql database in c# ? the below image shows few rows adding up. why is that? how to view the data in exact datagridview positions. 

![enter image description here][1]http://i.stack.imgur.com/hfQ7y.png          i want to delete everything for this purpose.

Comment: @Pret, you should edit your initial question and include this screenshot, code for getting data and code for populating grid. it will make question much more clear. also describe expected result, please

Comment: expected result for the above image should be like , all the data  which are viewed after few columns in that screenshot  must start from the first column itself.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/58Pzq.png expected output                                                   i ve commented the columns .. but without commenting is necessary.. using for loop or something?

Comment: @Pret, looks like grid creates new columns when you bind datasource. try set `DataPropertyName` for each existing column before binding (in code or in designer): `grid.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Name";` `grid.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Employee_id";` and so on;

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms:

for Row headers, set the property **RowHeadersVisible** of dataGridView,
for columns, use **ColumnHeadersVisible**

*Edit: @ASh, you were faster than me :)*

Comment: how to read dataset row by row from sql to datagridview?

Comment: @Pret: I am not sure that I did understand your question. However, build data tables (e.g. with a DataAdapter) by reading the database, then bind the datatable to DataGridView through a BindingSource. You will then be able to use the "Sort" and "Filter" properties of the bindingSource to reorder your rows or display an extract of the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

you can set ShowHeader property of gridview to False

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeader="False">
        </asp:GridView>
```

check the link
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheader(v=vs.110).aspx][1]

@Pret Response to your comment
Try This

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvSearchDetails" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True"   

                    PageSize="15" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

                    <Columns> 
                            <asp:BoundField   
                            DataField="Name"  >
                            </asp:BoundField>
                          <asp:BoundField   
                          DataField="Address"  > 
                        </asp:BoundField>
                 </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: how to view the data in datagridview from sql database in c# ? the below image shows few rows adding up. why is that? how to view the data in exact datagridview positions. ![enter image description here][1]i.stack.imgur.com/hfQ7y.png   
                                                                                          i.stack.imgur.com/58Pzq.png expected output i ve commented the columns .. but without commenting is necessary.. using for loop or something?